# Windows Azure Sockets

Tags: .net, networking, azure, cloud

Is it possible to connect to remote TCP sockets using windows azure cloud? I've read it's only possible to receive on port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 3):

Long ago, there were limits with Web roles. Not any more. When you set up your Role (your Virtual Machine), whether Web Role (meaning it's running IIS) or Worker Role (meaning it's not running IIS), you can expose endpoints with tcp, http, and https. You choose the port number.

You can open up to 25 endpoints in a given deployment.

Comment: Does it mean i can only open 25 sockets simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, but these sockets are open across all role instances. So if you have 10 instances, and you open an endpoint on, say, port 8080, each of those instances can listen on 8080. The traffic is then load-balanced across your instances. If you need more than 25 discrete port numbers, you can partition your application into multiple services (multiple deployments).

Comment: Lets say i need 10.000 socket connections to a remote service - would i need 400 deployments then?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood - I thought you were referring to a specific number of ports. You can accept multiple simultaneous connectoins on a given port within a single instance, just like any Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

With any type of Windows Azure role, you can define tcp endpoints and assign a specific port to each endpoint. You can then start a ServiceHost that listens on that tcp endpoint.The Windows Azure load balancer would take care of sending requests across your instances.

Azure allows only incoming ports 80 and 443 and you can use throw the WebRole. The worker role cannot listen to incoming messages from outside Azure.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand this answer, but the way it's worded is incorrect. Worker Roles are just like Web Roles - you can listen on any incoming tcp port you define, and these enpoints (as long as they're marked Input Endpoints) are exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows:

1. Create Azure Cloud service, in this service create Worker Role add an endpoint and choose your any port (You can also use Service Actor of Service Fabric).
2. Create and handle the Run event, in this Run method add a listener.
3. Capture the BeginAcceptSocket event (or BeginAcceptTCPClient if you like)
4. In the call back function of BeginAcceptSocket event, add a handler for BeginReceive event.
5. In the call back of BeginReceive event, you can add any code to manipulate the message from client.